# Should std::apply only apply to std::tuple?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, stdtuple, stdapply

The function signature of `std::apply` does not constrain the template parameter `Tuple` to be a specialization of `std::tuple`, so it can still accept a *tuple-like objects* that defines `std::tuple_size_v` ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/G36eqEabE)):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <array>

int main() {
  std::apply([](int, int) {}, std::array{0, 0});
  std::apply([](int, int) {}, std::pair {0, 0});
  std::apply([](int, int) {}, std::tuple{0, 0});
}
```

But the description of `std::apply` in [[tuple.apply]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/tuple#apply) is:

> 20.5.5 Calling a function with a **`tuple`** of arguments

Does this mean that applying `std::apply` to objects other than `std::tuple` is undefined behavior?

Comment: [This note](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/tuple#creation-11) may pertain to `tuple_cat`, but I don't see why implementations can't do it for everything in the `tuple` header.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 20.5.5 Calling a function with a `tuple` of arguments

I highly doubt that the section titles are normative.

The actual function is described as [being equivalent to the reference implementation](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/tuple#apply), which uses `get` and `tuple_size_v` to inspect the "tuple" parameter.

Cppreference [concurs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply).

Comment: @康桓瑋 Oops, I've removed the part about user-defined types. I wonder why `make_from_tuple`, which is defined right next to it, uses unqualified `get`...

Comment: They use `std::get`, not unqualified ones, per [contents]/3  https://eel.is/c++draft/contents#3.